# How to add two variables of type date?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, sql, content-builder

Good afternoon people!

I have a problem and after a lot of research I still don't know how to solve it

I have two variables @travel_time and @trip_duration, where I need to add the hours and minutes of the second to the first and create a new variable called @arrival_time

I didn't see any way to do this operation in ampscript

Does anyone know of a way I can help myself? I've been stuck on this task for 3 days

Example:

```
%%[
set @data1 = @travel_time 
set @data2 = @arrival_time 
]%%
%%=v(@data1)=%% %%=v(@ data2)=%% 

______________________________________ 
21:00:00.000Z     08:00:00.000Z 
______________________    
04:00:00.000Z     02:55:00.000Z
```

Comment: So basically you are looking to take the time of departure (`@travel_time`) and then take the duration (`@trip_duration`) and add that time onto the departure to get 'estimated arrival' time (`@arrival_time`)? If so, could you provide a sample of the data in these fields so we can see format and data types?

Comment: `set @data1 = @travel_time
set @data2 = @arrival_time
%%=v(@data1)=%%
%%=v(@ data2)=%%
______________________________________
21:00:00.000Z    
08:00:00.000Z
______________________
 

04:00:00.000Z
02:55:00.000Z
`

Comment: Is it just the time or is it date time format? E.g. `HH:MM:SS.mmmZ` (10:41:12.932Z) or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmmZ` (2023-01-25T01:22:32.234Z)? This will change the way the date math is handled.

Answer (score 0):

That should look something like this:

```
set @hour_offset = DatePart(@trip_duration, "H");
set @minute_offset = DatePart(@trip_duration, "MI");
set @travel_time = DateAdd(@trip_duration, @hour_offset, "H");
set @travel_time = DateAdd(@travel_time, @minute_offset, "MI");
```

We extract the hours and minutes, then add them consecutively to form the new value. Note that `DateAdd` returns a new, independent date, so we have to use `@travel_time` in the second calculation.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the sum is not correct, some examples that are returning:

'04:00:00.000Z 02:55:00.000Z 01/25/2023 05:50:00'

'15:04:00.000Z 03:51:00.000Z 01/25/2023 07:42:00'

Comment: @felipemartins Hmm, not sure what to say. Maybe you could just extract the values with DatePart, add the times together, then create a new date value?